# Feed non-placeholder variables in seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm playing with Tensorflow seq2seq model and I'm wondering how I can feed a trained seq2seq decoder with an arbitrary initial decoder memory (during the training, this initial decoder memory is an output of the encoder).

I figured that I need to use feed_dict and TF forces me to feed input sequence because a placeholder is defined for it, same for decoder input.

But if I do so, I can't actually force the initial decoder memory to be what I want it to be because it's defined from the decoder input. I still tried to do it but it ignores my third line.

```
for t in range(seq_length):
    feed_dict[enc_inp[t]] = X[t] #encoder input

for t in range(seq_length):
    feed_dict[dec_inp[t]] = Y[t] #decoder input

for t in range(seq_length):
    feed_dict[dec_memory[t]] = np.random.rand(memory_dim) #value I want to feed as initial memory of decode
```

Do you have any clue on how to do what I want ? ie feeding the model variables states even though they aren't designed to be fed by placeholders.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can feed any node. If you don't see an effect of your feeding, perhaps your output doesn't depend on the node you fed

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be feeding random numbers, but rather 0's? That's a suggestion in the karpathy lesson on rnns: [Recurrent Neural Networks, Image Captioning](https://youtu.be/cO0a0QYmFm8?list=PLlJy-eBtNFt6EuMxFYRiNRS07MCWN5UIA)

Comment: The decoder is trained for generation from a sentence embedding. I wanted to generate random sentences with random characteristics